# Detect pairs after simple frequency

Tags: r, quanteda

After these steps:

```
library(quanteda)

df <- data.frame(text = c("only a small text","only a small text","only a small text","only a small text","only a small text","only a small text","remove this word lower frequency"))
tdfm <- df$text %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE) %>%
  dfm()
dfm_keep(tdfm, pattern = featnames(tdfm)[docfreq(tdfm) > 5])
```

How is it possible to find pairs or triples of words (ngram = 2:3) which exist in more than 5 documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngrams need to be constructed before converting to dfm. Because the order of words in a dfm is lost.

The clean quanteda way then would be:

```r
library(quanteda)

df <- data.frame(text = c("only a small text","only a small text","only a small text","only a small text","only a small text","only a small text","remove this word lower frequency"))
tdfm <- df %>%
  corpus() %>%                        # when you have a data.frame it usually makes sense to construct a corpus first to retain the other columns as meta-data
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, 
         remove_numbers = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_ngrams(n = 2:3) %>%          # construct ngrams
  dfm() %>%                           # convert to dfm
  dfm_trim(min_docfreq = 5)           # select ngrams that appear in at least 5 documents

tdfm
#> Document-feature matrix of: 7 documents, 5 features (14.3% sparse).
#>        features
#> docs    only_a a_small small_text only_a_small a_small_text
#>   text1      1       1          1            1            1
#>   text2      1       1          1            1            1
#>   text3      1       1          1            1            1
#>   text4      1       1          1            1            1
#>   text5      1       1          1            1            1
#>   text6      1       1          1            1            1
#> [ reached max_ndoc ... 1 more document ]
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### Update based on comment

If you want to create ngrams only from words which appear in more than 4 documents, I think it makes most sense to first construct a dfm without ngrams, filter terms that appear in more than 4 docs and use this dfm to subset the tokens before constructing ngrams (as no tokens_trim function exists):

```r
# first construct dfm without ngrams and
dfm_onegram <- df %>%
  corpus() %>%      
  dfm() %>%                           
  dfm_trim(min_docfreq = 4) 

dfm_ngram <- df %>% 
  corpus() %>% 
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, 
         remove_numbers = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_keep(featnames(dfm_onegram)) %>% # keep only tokens that appear in more than 4 docs (in the dfm_onegram object)
  tokens_ngrams(n = 2:3) %>%         
  dfm() %>%
  dfm_trim(min_docfreq = 5)
```

Keep in mind though that rare words will now be ignored when in ngrams. If you have the text "only a rare small text", the resulting ngram will still be "only_a_small".

Comment: If I would like to remove based on min_docfreq = 4 before the ngram, make the ngram and again remove documents based of min_docfreq = 5 is it possible to make it?

Answer (score 1):

As in the previous question, just expand what you are looking for.

```
tdfm <- df$text %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE) %>%
  # 2 and 3 grams
  tokens_ngrams(n = 2:3) %>% 
  dfm()
           
dfm_keep(tdfm, pattern = featnames(tdfm)[docfreq(tdfm) > 5])
Document-feature matrix of: 7 documents, 5 features (14.3% sparse).
       features
docs    only_a a_small small_text only_a_small a_small_text
  text1      1       1          1            1            1
  text2      1       1          1            1            1
  text3      1       1          1            1            1
  text4      1       1          1            1            1
  text5      1       1          1            1            1
  text6      1       1          1            1            1
  text7      0       0          0            0            0
```